# regroup uneven number of rows pandas df

Tags: pandas, group-by

[image: image showing the current format and how would like to format]

I need to regroup a df from the above format in the one below but it fails and the output shape is (unique number of IDs, 2). Is there a more obvious solution?

Comment: Can you provide your dataframes as code or text, not as an image? Your grouped data doesn't match your source data (second value in group `7` should be `0.2`).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I solved like that: Y0= Y.groupby(by = ['A'])['col'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str))).reset_index()

Y0_expand = Y0['col'].str.split(pat =',', n=-1, expand =True).astype(np.float64).  However, the problem is that i need more accuracy 6 decimals places so float64 only returns 4. If I use np.float128 it is not supported when I try to fill in the nas Y0_expand.fillna(method = 'bfill', axis=0, inplace =True)
Any, better solution maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` and `pivot`:

```
(df.assign(n=df.groupby('ID').cumcount().add(1))
   .pivot(index='ID', columns='n', values='Value')
   .add_prefix('val_')
   .reset_index()
)
```

Example input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [7,7,8,11,12,18,22,22,22],
                   'Value': list('abcdefghi')})
```

Output:

```
n    ID val_1 val_2 val_3
0     7     a     b   NaN
1     8     c   NaN   NaN
2    11     d   NaN   NaN
3    12     e   NaN   NaN
4    18     f   NaN   NaN
5    22     g     h     i
```